# qs stringify with empty string as key (e.g. {"":value})

Tags: javascript, json, query-string

I need to make a request with only URL parameters where the only thing I want to pass is an object that has a single empty key and a value. I know it's a little odd to have an object with a key qual to `""` but that part wasn't my decision.

When I go to encode the object though, my object gets converted to an array with value as the only item. Any idea how I can keep it as an object?

```
const q = {items: {'': 'value'}};
const q_string = qs.stringify(q);
const q_parsed = qs.parse(q_string);
console.log(q) # {items: {'': 'value'}}
console.log(q_string) # items%5B%5D=value
console.log(q_parsed) # {items: ['value']}
```

Comment: I'm exploring that but the output isn't exactly the same as qs

Comment: What exactly do you want the query string to look like?

Comment: I've been trying to make it resemble the query_string so that it doesn't need to be JSON parsed server side